# How do I set my foreign key to grab a row in my other table? Laravel 8 Debugging

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

UPDATED: this is my latest [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDMd4.jpg). How do I set the 'food_id' to grab 'id' from food table? I have referenced it to the 'id' but it still doesn't have any value. Can someone help?
Thanks!

Here is all my codes. I have two tables of foods and images. and I'm trying to let my 'food_id' from images, to get 'id' which is from food table. I tried to combine codes of storing a product's data and image(s) in my store function( i did this because i want to use only one form in my view.).  if you're unclear from my codes, feel free to ask :))

In migration create_images_table.php

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('food_id');
        $table->String('filename');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('food_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('food')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

In my FoodController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Images;
use App\Models\Cart;
use App\Models\Food;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'filename' => 'required',
        'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    
    if ($request->hasfile('filename')) {
        foreach ($request->file('filename') as $image) {
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path() . '/images', $name); // folder path
            $data[] = $name;
        }
    }

    $Upload_model = new Images;
    $Upload_model->filename = json_encode($data);
    $Upload_model->save();

    $foods = new Food([
        'name'            =>  $request->get('name'),
        'description'     =>  $request->get('description'),
        'price'           =>  $request->get('price'),
        // column name => frontend name
    ]);

    $foods->save();

    session()->flash('success', 'Food successfully added.');
    return redirect()->route('welcome');
}
```

In my create.blade.php

```
@section('content')
<div class="w3-container w3-black w3-padding-64 w3-xxlarge" id="cart">
    <div class="w3-content">
        <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32 w3-sand">
            <h1 class="w3-center">
            <span> Add New Food </span>
            </h1>
            <hr class="new1">
            
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('food.store') }}">
                @csrf
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Food Name" required name="name"></p>
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Description" required name="description"></p>
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Price" required name="price"></p>
                <label> Images </label>
                <p><input class="class-control" type="file" placeholder="filename" required name="filename[]" multiple></p>
                <p><button class="w3-button w3-dark-grey w3-block  w3-hover-green" type="submit"> ADD! </button></p>
            </form>   

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

In my web.php

```
// Food Routes
Route::resources([
    'food' => App\Http\Controllers\FoodController::class,
]);
```

Comment: We really need to see your code

Comment: alright wait a sec

Comment: First of all, you need to check the received arguments in the request using `dd( $request->all() );` try it and post the result in the question too.

Comment: All the data were missing or only the images' data?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I got it solved now but it throws this [error](https://imgur.com/a/7y0B9i1). food_id is a foreign key connected to the id in food table. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi all of em is missing

Comment: now images is the only one missing, i got the foods values sent to food table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating an entry with relationship, you must specify which entry on the food table to relate with food_id column in the images table.
You should create food entry before images entry.

```
$foods = new Food([
    'name'            =>  $request->get('name'),
    'description'     =>  $request->get('description'),
    'price'           =>  $request->get('price'),
    // column name => frontend name
]);
$foods->save();
```

After creating the foods entry, you can specify the food_id from the foods object by,

```
$Upload_model = new Images;
$Upload_model->filename = json_encode($data);
$upload_modal->food_id = $foods->id:
$Upload_model->save();
```